# Should @Transient property be used in equals/hashCode/toString?

Tags: java, orm, jpa, transient

I have JPA entities where some properties are annotated with `@Transient`.

Should I use these properties in `equals/hashCode/toString` methods?

My first thought is **NO** but I don't know why.

- Tips?
- Ideas?
- Explanations?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The case of `toString()` is different, you can do whatever you want with `toString()` so I will only cover `equals()` (and `hashCode()`).

First, the rule: *if you want to store an object in a `List`, `Map` or a `Set` **then it is a requirement that `equals`  and `hashCode` are implemented** so they obey the standard contract as specified in the  documentation*.

Now, how to implement `equals()` and `hashCode()`? A "natural" idea would be to use the properties mapped as `Id` as part of the `equals()`:

```
public class User {
    ...
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if (this==other) return true;
        if (id==null) return false;
        if ( !(other instanceof User) ) return false;
        final User that = (User) other;
        return this.id.equals( that.getId() );
    }
    public int hashCode() {
        return id==null ? System.identityHashCode(this) : id.hashCode();
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, this solution has a **major problem**: when using generated identifiers, the values are not assigned until an entity becomes *persistent* so if a *transient* entity is added to a `Set` before being saved, its hash code will change while it's in the `Set` and this breaks the contract of the `Set`.

The recommended approach is thus to use the attributes that are part of the *business key* i.e. a combination of attributes that is unique for each instance with the same database identity. For example, for the User class, this could be the username:

```
public class User {
    ...
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if (this==other) return true;
        if ( !(other instanceof User) ) return false;
        final User that = (User) other;
        return this.username.equals( that.getUsername() );
    }
    public int hashCode() {
        return username.hashCode();
  }
}
```

The Hibernate Reference Documentation summarizes this as follow:

> "**Never use the database identifier to implement equality; use a business key, a combination of unique, usually immutable, attributes**. The database identifier will change if a transient object is made persistent. If the transient instance (usually together with detached instances) is held in a `Set`, changing the `hashcode` breaks the contract of the `Set`. Attributes for business keys don't have to be as stable as database primary keys, you only have to guarantee stability as long as the objects are in the same Set." - [12.1.3. Considering object identity](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/transactions.html#transactions-basics-identity)
>
> "**It is recommended that you implement `equals()` and `hashCode()` using Business key equality**. Business key equality means that the `equals()` method compares only the properties that form the business key. It is a key that would identify our instance in the real world (a natural candidate key)" - [4.3. Implementing equals() and hashCode()](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/persistent-classes.html#persistent-classes-equalshashcode)

So, back to the initial question:

- Use a business key if possible. `@Transient` attributes are very likely not part of such a key.
- If not possible, use identifier properties but make sure to get the values assigned before to add an entity to a `List`, `Map`, `Set`.

#### See also

- [Equals and HashCode](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/EqualsandHashCode)
- [Don't Let Hibernate Steal Your Identity](http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2006/09/13/dont-let-hibernate-steal-your-identity.html)
- [equals and hashcode in Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638723/equals-and-hashcode-in-hibernate)
- *Understanding equals() and hashCode()* (p. 396) in Java Persistence with Hibernate

Answer (score 0):

The two typical usages of `@Transient` and `transient` that I'm aware of, are to use them either for stuff that can't be serialized/persisted (e.g. a remote resource *handle*) or computed properties which can be reconstructed from others.

For **computed data**, it makes no sense to use them in the equality relationship (`equals/hashCode`), because it would be redundant. The value is computed out of other value which are already used in the equality. It can however still makes sense to print them in `toString` (e.g. a base price and a ratio are used to compute the actual price).

For **not serializable/persitable data**, it depends. I can imagine a handle to a resource that is not serializable, but you can still compare the resource name that the handle represent. Same for `toString`, maybe printing the handle resource name is useful.

This was my 2 cent, but if you explain your particular usage of `@Transient`, someone can maybe give a better advice.

Answer (score 0):

Exception maybe comes from letting it be `transient` and at the same time you provide   `writeObject()` and `readObject()` where you process it.