# EntityManager does not update on flush()

Tags: jpa, entity-relationship, flush, entitymanager

Java EJB's EntityManager does not update data from a Consumer.

A Consumer logs into a shop, buys some stuff and wants to look at his shopping-history. Everything is displayed but his last purchase. If he logs out and in, it shows.

I have used JPA to persist buys/purchases (that are mapped to the Consumer)to DB. It seems like purchases from this session can't be detected.

Code:

```
public Buys buyItem(Consumer c, int amount) {
    Buys b = new Buys();
    b.setConsumerId(c);
    b.setContent("DVD");
    b.setPrice(amount);
    em.persist(b);
    em.flush();
    return b;
}

public Collection getAllBuysFromUser(Consumer consumer) {
   Collection<Buys> collection = consumer.getBuysCollection();
   return collection;
}
```

Help!? Flush does not do the trick...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have a bi-directional one-to-many association between `Customer` and `Buys` but I don't see where you add the `Buys` instance to the `buysCollection` on the `Customer` side. I'd expect to see something like this:

```
public Buys buyItem(Consumer c, int amount) {
    Buys b = new Buys();
    b.setConsumerId(c);
    b.setContent("DVD");
    b.setPrice(amount);
    c.getBuysCollection().add(b);
    em.persist(b);
    em.flush();
    return b;
}
```

And make sure you [implement `equals` (and `hashCode`) properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2951454/should-transient-property-be-used-in-equals-hashcode-tostring/2952469#2952469).

I suggest to check [1.2.6. Working bi-directional links](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/tutorial.html#tutorial-associations-usingbidir) (and to add defensive link management methods as suggested).