# Prevent Mixin overriding equals from breaking case class equality

Tags: scala, squeryl

`Squeryl` defines a trait `KeyedEntity` which overrides `equals`, checking for several conditions in an if and calling `super.equals` in the end.  Since `super` is `Object`, it will always fail.

Consider:

```
trait T { override def equals(z: Any):Boolean = super.equals(z)} }

case class A(a: Int) extends T

val a = A(1); val b = A(1)

a==b // false
```

Thus, if you declare

```
case class Record(id: Long, name: String ...) extends KeyedEntity[Long] { ... }
```

-- and you create several `Record` instances but do not persist them, their comparison will break.  I found this by implementing both `Salat` and `Squeryl` back ends for the same class, and then all `Salat` tests fail since `isPersisted` from `KeyedEntity` is false.

Is there a design whereby `KeyedEntity` will preserve case class equality if mixed into a case class?  I tried self-typing and parameterizing `BetterKeyedEntity[K,P] { self: P => ... }` for the case class type as P but it causes infinite recursion in equals.

As things stand right now, `super` is `Object` so the final branch of the overridden equals in `KeyedEntity` will always return false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The structural equality check usually generated for case classes seems not to be generated if there is an `equals` override. However some subtleties have to be noted.

Mixing the concept of id-based equality falling back to structural equality **might not be a good idea**, since I can imagine that it may lead to subtle bugs. For example:

- `x: A(1)` and and `y: A(1)` are not yet persisted, so they are equal
- then they get persisted, and since they are separate objects, the persistence framework may persist them as separate entities (I don't know Squeryl, maybe not an issue there, but this is a thin line to walk)
- after persisting, they are suddenly not equal since the id differs.

Even worse, if `x` and `y` get persisted to the same id, the `hashCode` will differ before and after persisting ([the source](https://github.com/max-l/Squeryl/blob/master/src/main/scala/org/squeryl/KeyedEntity.scala) shows that if persisted it is the hashCode of the id). This breaks immutability, and will lead to very bad behavior (when put in maps for example). See [this gist in which I demonstrate the assert failing](https://gist.github.com/3726916).

So don't mix structural and id-based equality *implicitly*.  Also see this explained in the [context of Hibernate.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638723/equals-and-hashcode-in-hibernate)

**Typeclasses**

It have to be noted that others pointed out (ref needed) that the concept of method-based equality is flawed, for such reasons (there is not only one way two thing can be equal). Therefore you can define a typeclass which describes Equality:

```
trait Eq[A] {
  def equal(x: A, y: A): Boolean
}
```

and define (possibly multiple) instances of that typeclass for your classes:

```
// structural equality
implicit object MyClassEqual extends Eq[MyClass] { ... }

// id based equality
def idEq[K, A <: KeyedEntity[K]]: Eq[A] = new Eq[A] {
  def equal(x: A, y: A) = x.id == y.id
}
```

then you can request that things are members of the Eq typeclass:

```
def useSomeObjects[A](a: A, b: A)(implicit aEq: Eq[A]) = {
  ... aEq.equal(a, b) ...
}
```

So you can decide which notion of equality to use by importing the appropriate typeclass in scope, or passing the typeclass instance directly as in `useSomeObjects(x, y)(idEq[Int, SomeClass])`

Note that you might also need a `Hashable` typeclass, similarly.

**Autogenerating Eq instances**

This situation is pretty similar to the Scala stdlib's `scala.math.Ordering` typeclass. Here is an example for [auto-deriving structural `Ordering` instances for case classes](https://gist.github.com/3705819) using the excellent [shapeless](https://www.google.hu/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCQQFjAA&url=https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless&ei=SSxUUMuhOsXtsgbr24HABA&usg=AFQjCNFvx3dfQCrdoYO7rK_GCYBDLKxxQA&sig2=OXRlsO9QlRRkEB5Heo3hcA) library.

The same would easy to be done for `Eq` and `Hashable`.

**Scalaz**

Note that [scalaz has `Equal` typeclass](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/scalaz-seven/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Equal.scala), with nice pimp patterns with which you can write `x === y` instead of `eqInstance.equal(x, y)`. I'm not aware it has `Hashable` typeclass, yet.

Comment: Thanks Ron!  Apparently this approach was already taken by Sqyeryl: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/squeryl/kFvX_uvIxdI/discussion