# Storing java entities in hashmap for faster retrieval

Tags: java, hibernate, caching, hash

I have an object so that

```
class MyObj{
    public long id_1;
    ... 
}
```

My HBM (hibernate mapping file) tells that this id_1 is my Id. Now what i want to do is to cache this entity in HashMap so that `HashMap<MyObj, NestObj>` i.e., `MyObj` will become the key for the hashMap.

Now the question that I wanted to ask

I want to make sure that even though i have saved the whole object as the key, I want to keep object retrieval/storing in the hashmap based on the `MyObj.id_1` value. The easiest way i can do so is to after retrieving all objects, I have to do a for loop to add them in a map as `Map <Integer, MyObj>` but in that case i would have maintain two maps (one for `MyObj` and other for `NestedObj`) which i want to avoid.

How can i dictate my HashMap to use `MyObj.id_1` column to use as comparator, hash etc. Shall i override `hash` and `equal` function ? But if i do so, would it affect hibnerate comparison while storing/retrieving entities ?

Comment: If you want to lookup the map using id_1. Why not store that as the key and save MyObj and NestObj as a compound value (you can choose your data structure) ? For example HashMap<Long, Map<MyObj, NestObj>>. I assume you need other attributes of MyObj once you look it up.

Comment: Yup, thats another approach. But i wanted to take this problem as an opportunity to understand more how can i leverage existing object hash/equal methods used by java collection.

Comment: Your question suggests you already know that. The only issue is how it would affect Hibernate. Check this out for that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638723/equals-and-hashcode-in-hibernate. I don't know your problem domain but I would never override equals and hashcode based on one use case of hashing requirement.

Comment: With reference to @ShireResident's comment, you probably don't need a `Map` as the value  but just a `Pair`. `HashMap` uses the key's natural `equals` and `hashCode` but you can trivially wrap it in another class that uses `MyObj.id_` for both

Comment: is it any good reason why you don't want to use build in caching mechanism?

Comment: I am new to spring, don't know anything about it. so i am trying to figure out what options are better. As long as built-in mechanism doesn't require extra configuration, imight be okay with it. Can you give me some pointers on that ?