# Hibernate: Cannot fetch data back to Map<>

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, crud

having this Entities:

*User.java*:

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class User {
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    private String username;
    private String about;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "owner", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Map<User, Friendship> friendships = new HashMap<>();
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "author", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Collection<Post> posts = new ArrayList<>();

    public User(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public void addFriend(User friend){
        Friendship friendship = new Friendship();
        friendship.setOwner(this);
        friendship.setFriend(friend);
        this.friendships.put(friend, friendship);
    }

    public void addPost(Post post){
        post.setAuthor(this);
        this.posts.add(post);
    }
}
```

*Friendship.java*:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Friendship {
    @EmbeddedId
    private FriendshipId key = new FriendshipId();
    private String level;
    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("ownerId")
    private User owner;
    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("friendId")
    private User friend;
}
```

*FriendshipId.java*:

```
@Embeddable
public class FriendshipId implements Serializable {
    private int ownerId;
    private int friendId;
}
```

*UserRepository.java*:

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {
    public User findByUsername(String username);
}
```

and finaly *DemoApplication.java*:

```
@Bean
    public CommandLineRunner dataLoader(UserRepository userRepo, FriendshipRepository friendshipRepo){
        return new CommandLineRunner() {
            @Override
            public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
                User f1 = new User("friend1");
                User f2 = new User("friend2");
                User u1 = new User("user1");

                u1.addFriend(f1);
                u1.addFriend(f2);
                userRepo.save(u1);

                User fetchedUser = userRepo.findByUsername("user1");
            System.out.println(fetchedUser);
            System.out.println(fetchedUser.getFriendships().get(f1));

            }
        };
    }
```

After the `userRepo.save(u1)` operation, the tables are as follows:

```
mysql> select * from user;
+----+-------+----------+
| id | about | username |
+----+-------+----------+
|  1 | NULL  | user1    |
|  2 | NULL  | friend1  |
|  3 | NULL  | friend2  |
+----+-------+----------+

select * from friendship;
+-------+-----------+----------+-----------------+
| level | friend_id | owner_id | friendships_key |
+-------+-----------+----------+-----------------+
| NULL  |         2 |        1 |               2 |
| NULL  |         3 |        1 |               3 |
+-------+-----------+----------+-----------------+
```

As you can see all friends were saved. However this statement:

```
        System.out.println(fetchedUser.getFriendships().get(f1));
```

returns `null`. Even though the `fetchedUser` has the Map of friends fetched:

```
        System.out.println(fetchedUser);
```

prints:

```
User(id=1, username=user1, about=null, friendships={User(id=2, username=friend1, about=null, friendships={}, posts=[])=com.example.demo.model.Friendship@152581e8, User(id=3, username=friend2, about=null, friendships={}, posts=[])=com.example.demo.model.Friendship@58a5d38}, posts=[])
```

So why does the friend `f1` couldn't be fetched (more precisely is `null`), when the Map `friendships` is fully fetched (all friends are fetched, as you could see from the above statement) ?

PS:

I have deleted the `@Data` lombok annotation (just added `@Getter`,`@Setter` and @NoArgsConstrutor`) and overrided the equalsAndHashCode myself:

```
@Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof User)) return false;
        User user = (User) o;
        return id == user.id && Objects.equals(username, user.username) && Objects.equals(about, user.about) && Objects.equals(friendships, user.friendships) && Objects.equals(posts, user.posts);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id, username, about, friendships, posts);
    }
```

Or in other words, the `equals()` method uses all fields of the `User` class.

Comment: I think you are missing EqualsAndHashcode implementation.

Comment: @SKumar well the User has `@Data` lombok annotation which should override the EqualAndHascode.

Comment: Ok, but does it know that out of all fields in `User` class, it only needs to verify on `username` field ? `id` is also populated. Can you confirm that if you log `f1` it has `id` populated. I suspect it doesn't have it.

Comment: @SKumar I don't understand what you mean, but if you look at the edit, I have override the equals and hashCode myself (well the IDE did)

Comment: @SKumar the overrided `equals()` is using all fields now

Comment: I meant what is the output of `System.out.println(f1)` . Does it contain `id` field populated?

Comment: @SKumar it does `User{id=2, username='friend1', about='null', friendships={}, posts=[]}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As you can see all friends were saved. However this statement:
>
> ```
>     System.out.println(fetchedUser.getFriendships().get(f1)); returns null.
> ```
>
> Even though the fetchedUser has the Map of friends
> fetched:
>
> ```
>     System.out.println(fetchedUser);
> ```
>
> prints:
>
> ```
>  User(id=1, username=user1, about=null, friendships={User(id=2, username=friend1, about=null, friendships={}, posts=[])=com.example.demo.model.Friendship@152581e8, User(id=3, username=friend2, about=null, friendships={}, posts=[])=com.example.demo.model.Friendship@58a5d38}, posts=[])
> ```

The issue is that when the `f1` `User` is added to `friendships` HashMap, primary key `id` was not present. It gets updated later by Hibernate at some point. This changes the HashCode value !!!

`hashcode` value of a key should not be changed after it is added to a `Map`. This is causing the issue. Simple Test Code to simulate the issue - https://www.jdoodle.com/a/3Bg3

```
import lombok.*;
import java.util.*;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      Map<User, String> friendships = new HashMap<>();
        User f1 = new User();
        f1.setUsername("friend1");
        
        User f2 = new User();
        f2.setUsername("friend2");
        friendships.put(f1, "I am changed. Can't find me");
        friendships.put(f2, "Nothing changed. So, you found me");
        
        System.out.println(f1.hashCode()); // -600090900
        f1.setId(1); // Some id gets assigned by hibernate. Breaking the hashcode
        System.out.println(f1.hashCode()); // -600090841 (this changed !!!)

        System.out.println(friendships); // prints f1, f2 both
        System.out.println(friendships.get(f1)); // prints null
        System.out.println(friendships.get(f2));
    }
}

// @Data
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode
@ToString
class User
{
    private int id;
    private String username;
}
```

**Solution**

The `hashcode` value should not be changed after a User is added to the Map. I think there are couple of options which can be tried to solve this -

1. Persist the friends in the Database before it is put into the `friendship` Map. So that id is already assigned.
2. Don't override `equals` and `hashcode` at all. Work with defaults. Based on, object identities.
3. Use a fixed hashcode. For example, if `username` never changes after it is assigned, this field can be used to generate `hashcode` value.

Comment: Well the second point of not generating hash and equals at all... May be not ideal approach but do I really need to override this methods? If I am not explicitly using equals in my code, then do I really need it? I know the `Map<>` is using it, but I don't so I don't need to override it, right?

Comment: @milanHrabos Looks like you don't need to override those methods as this https://stackoverflow.com/q/1638723/11244881 explains.

Comment: The reason the `hashCode` is broken is not because of change of the `id`, but because of collection. Please look here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69142972/how-is-possible-the-map-will-find-the-right-element-when-the-hascode-of-that . I have made the `equalsAndHasCode` using only the `id`, and still it worked (but it shouldn't -> becuase as you said, the `id` is `null`, then assigned by hibernate when persisting). How is this possible?